# Comparing input value with else if statement don't work, what can i do?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, input

i just did a form, take is value into variable and try to compare them between each other, but nothing is happening.

I've tried to convert the variable in integer with number() and parseInt, didn't work.

I tried to declare the variable outside of the function, didn't work

```
$('#calculate').click(function(){
  var bill = $('#bill').val();
  var serveuse = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
  var sangs = $('#gars').val();
  if(bill===0){
    alert('something');
  }
  else if (bill<10){
    alert('somethinge else');
  }
  else(gars>10 &&bill>20){
    alert('something else else');
  }
})
```

There is three input in my from, 'sangs' and 'bill' are classical input type number, 'serveuse' is an select option input. I just want to compare those three variable with a lot of else if statement to output a result.

Comment: Post your full html . Also you use Identical Operator (===) which do strict comparison. try to use == instead.

Comment: Look at your browser's debugging console.  It's telling you what the error is.

Comment: *I've tried to convert the variable in integer with number() and parseInt, didn't work.* - show how you tried in the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m: No, but `else(gars>10 &&bill>20)` will.  It's syntactically incorrect and `gars` is undefined.  This is also a great opportunity for the OP to begin to familirarize himself with his browser's debugging tools in general, to be more specific than "it didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

probably `else(gars>10 &&bill>20)` must be `else if (gars>10 &&bill>20)`

and *gars* must be *sangs*

Answer (score 0):

`$('#bill').val()` will give you a string result, eg `"0"`.

```
`"0" !== 0`
```

so you need to convert it to a number first, eg

```
var bill = $('#bill').val() * 1;
```

Alternatively, use `==` which will convert automatically:  `"0" == 0`

---

Other issues:

```
var sangs = ...
if (gars > ...
```

and

```
if () { } else if () { } else () {}
```

is missing  `else`

You also have a large area of missing results, so you probably need a final `else` without an `if` clause (eg if bill == 11 then you won't get an alert)